# container to container access on windows server 2016 for windows containers problem

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows, docker-network

i want to run to containers in the same network:

docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '2.1'

    services:

        web:
            build:
                context: ./src/web
                dockerfile: web.Dockerfile
            image: somethingWeb
            container_name: smt-web 
            mem_limit: 2G
            restart: on-failure
            depends_on:
                - db

        db:
            build:
                context: ./src/db
                dockerfile: db.Dockerfile
            image: somethingDB
            container_name: smt-db
            ports:
                - ${EXPOSED_SQLSERVER_PORT?err}:1433
            environment:
                sa_password: "Lfdc82zo!"
                ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

but there is no ping from web to db:

```bsh
    PS C:\> ping db

        Pinging db [172.24.248.112] with 32 bytes of data:
        Request timed out.
        Request timed out.

        Ping statistics for 172.24.248.112:
            Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 0, Lost = 2 (100% loss),
```

I am running Windows Server 2016 on a vmware ESXI as an host. and containers are also windows server 2016 images.

**is there any suggestion to solve my container-to-container isolation problem?**

according to [this microsoft's article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/network-drivers-topologies) for NAT network i added Hyper-V feature to windows server 2016 ([from this](https://www.opentechguides.com/askotg/question/118/hyper-v-cannot-be-installed-the-processor-does-not-have-the-required-virtualization-capabilities)) and Hyper-V is enabled.

theser are my docker networks:

```
λ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
bb82f97a3679        mehdi_default       nat                 local
ee22d8faad51        nat                 nat                 local
0e05aee3cc5f        none                null                local
```

Comment: `Pinging db [172.24.248.112]` suggests that the docker network is properly configured (its getting an IP address for `db`). Ping is probably not the best tool for this, is your database not responding on the expected port? Is it set to listen on all interfaces?

Comment: container not able to see another container. port listening in each container is ok. and from out of containers i can see ports and IPs. but container-to-container connection is not possible. they also joined to the docker-compose nat network created!

Comment: What does `docker service ls` show?

Comment: i didn't setup Swarm for this machine . i only want to connect my web container to db container with docker-compose. that was the way i follow in windows 10 but not working on windows server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2016 has it's own NAT for Docker and this is a PITA because you have to expose your ports and each container has it's own internal IP. This was an issue for me as I couldn't get container to talk directly to each other. It was a simple Nuget server with 1 port exposed but I wasn't able to run that container as a service due to the IMHO broken Docker NAT for Server 2016.

I found that Microsoft fixed/changed docker support on any newer version of Windows Server after 2016 that allowed the network for Docker to act just like it does on OSX/Linux. So running a container and exposing a port uses the servers IP and not some random NAT IP.

Can you try using a Windows Server version 1803 or later, or Windows Server 2019? 
You can use docker inspect to find the running containers port/IP. This is helpful when trying to talk cross containers in 2016 as you are using the exact network address:port which may be required due to the MS NAT for Docker. My workaround for 2016 was using the MS NAT service to route traffic externally to the continer via NAT rule that really passed traffic to the docker container. This was a problem if the server restarted because the container got a new IP requiring the MS server NAT service endpoint IP to be updated, but it worked. This all could be scripted but I felt like it was hacky already using the MS NAT service to talk to the container running a service. So I moved to 2019 and didn't need any of this NAT hacky stuff.